# DNS Zone manager - Server name and NS records mismatch. Pingdom errors

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, monitoring

http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=leadassign.com&timestamp=1413917580&view=1

Lists errors:  "Superfluous name server listed at parent: ns1.io-servers.com.", etc.

I think its because in the GUI zone file editor at our host we currently have:

```
 Server Name #1 ns1.io-servers.com Server Name #2 ns2.io-servers.com

Then in the NS records section: 
  NS Records
          ns1.panelboxmanager.com   14400   
          ns2.panelboxmanager.com   14400
```

Should I change the NS records to use ns1.io-servers.com instead of ns1.panelboxmanager.com ?

The domain is not in widespread use yet. I'm a bit of a newbie at this - not sure what pingdom means when then say "Total parent/child glue mismatch" or "Superfluous name server listed at parent: ns1.io-servers.com"

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name servers you have listed with your DNS registrar don't match those provided by your DNS servers.  Make sure you use the same names both palaces.

There are also indications that you have DNS updates that haven't been picked up by your secondary name server.  You should have a master name server where you make updates, and configure the slave to accept updates from the master.

If you have a simple domain, it may be simplest to not run your own name servers.  Many registrars include hosting basic DNS entries as part of the registration process.  They may charge for enhanced DNS services.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that the name servers should match. We need things like txt records, custom CNAMEs subdomains, etc so the default hosted one was not working for us.